# Hiveserver2 is stuck in starting mode in cloudera

Tags: postgresql, hive, cloudera-manager

Having some trouble. Using Cloudera Manager 4.6.3 . The hiveserver2 role is stuck in the Role State of "Starting". The processes are currently down. I cannot stop, start, or delete. The hivemetastore is "Started". I can connect to hive, but not to hive2. I believe I am using PostgreSQL as the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out! The process was running, but the state was stuck in "starting". I am using PostgreSQL for Cloudera Metadata, and did the following steps:

Got Postgres Password:

```
sudo more /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt
```

Logged  into Postgres:

```
psql -U cloudera-scm -p 7432 -h localhost -d postgres
```

List DB's and Tables:

```
list or \l: list all databases
```

Found a Database called SCM. Just figured that was the one.

Connected to SCM:

```
\connect SCM
```

List all tables in the current database:

```
\dt
```

Found a table called `ROLES`.

Ran the following:

```
update ROLES set configured_status = 'RUNNING' where configured_status = 'STARTING' and role_type = 'HIVESERVER2'
```

Went back to the Cloudera Management screen and  Viola! Now I have control to stop/start/etc!